# Vertical scanlines on old laptop (Sony Vaio circa 2010) screen after upgrading to Windows 10

Tags: display, display-driver

I'm trying to upgrade a very old Sony Vaio (from 2010) to Windows 10.
After updating it, the screen got a strange scanline effect:

[image]

The shades of gray are displayed correctly, but all colors are ignored every 1 pixel column. 
Like:

```
Color + Grayscale + Color + Grayscale
```

Also, the right side of the screen has a 10 pixel wide column which is totally corrupted (Display only a greyish color, with some columns scrambled).

It even happens inside the BIOS.

What's happening with the screen?
Is this a faulty screen?

I already tried to install the latest drivers from Sony.

### EDIT

I ended up reverting to Windows 7. While inside the BIOS, the same problem keeps happening.

You can see in the non-grayish parts, the pattern is there.
[image]
[image]

Windows 7 is displayed normally.
[image]

Now I just wished to understand what kind of bug would cause that pattern.

Comment: "It even happens inside the BIOS."  This is a hardware problem and not a Windows 10 problem.  Probably time to replace the machine.

Comment: Yeah... Strange that it happened after updating to Windows 10. When I first booted the machine with Windows 7, it was working normally.

Comment: Strange that Windows 7 works and BIOS does not. Still, the machine is probably too old for Windows 10

Comment: It is also possible the BIOS was changed somehow when you upgraded.

Comment: I just reverted back to Windows 7 and it's working normally. 
Inside the BIOS, the problem keeps happening. I updated the post with more pics.

I'm going to say to the owner that is time to let it go...

Comment: If I post the appropriate answer, will you acknowledge it?

Comment: Yes. The answer in this case is "buy a new laptop" ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange that Windows 7 works and BIOS does not. So based on all your information, the machine is probably too old for Windows 10 and time to replace it.

Comment: John, downvoted this “answer” because — as you do fairly regularly — you simply post comments as answer. Yes, this “answer” was accepted but the whole question is too broad at best.

Comment: The question was quite reasonable and the answer I provided fitted it very well.